# Spring Bean tenantEntityManager error: Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, spring

estou tendo um erro ao tentar executar a minha aplicação JSF com Spring, mais especificamente:

-tenho um método para fazer uma busca de crachás em certos repositórios e alterá-los após executar método em um controller;

-o erro começou a aparecer após eu estar criando as variadas classes nas quais possuem crachás de funcionários e devem ser alteradas;

-eu estava criando-as na ordem: classe primeiro, depois o repositório da própria classe, injetando-o no controlador responsável pela troca com a anotação `@Autowired;`

-o erro não fez muito sentido para mim devido ao fato que simplesmente ao criar uma classe mesmo sem fazer um @JoinColumn referente a tabela que aparentemente está causando o erro, ele ocorre;

aí está o erro:

```
----------
2019-03-20 13:20:05.569  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-03-20 13:20:05.569  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-03-20 13:20:05.580  WARN 11056 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000006: Attempted to specify unsupported NamingStrategy via setting [hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy]; NamingStrategy has been removed in favor of the split ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy; use [hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy] or [hibernate.physical_naming_strategy], respectively, instead.
2019-03-20 13:20:05.807  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-03-20 13:20:05.967  WARN 11056 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       : HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: XPROJECT.REP
2019-03-20 13:20:05.977  WARN 11056 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantEntityManager' defined in class path resource [X/Y/Z/configuration/MultiTenancyJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name fun_empresa in table CADFUN
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantEntityManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2019-03-20 13:20:05.978  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'master'
2019-03-20 13:20:05.979  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Close initiated...
2019-03-20 13:20:06.855  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Closed.
2019-03-20 13:20:06.858  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-03-20 13:20:06.877  INFO 11056 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-20 13:20:06.881 ERROR 11056 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantEntityManager' defined in class path resource [X/Y/Z/configuration/MultiTenancyJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name fun_empresa in table CADFUN
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at X.Y.Z.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name fun_empresa in table CADFUN
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:997) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getPhysicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:966) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.findPropertiesByColumns(BinderHelper.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

EDIT 1: a coluna lógica fun_empresa existe sim na tabela cadfun:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

-MAPEAMENTO DA FUNCIONARIO(CADFUN):

```
package X.Y.Z.model.tenancy;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils;

import br.com.mhfsistemas.util.BoolUtils;
import br.com.mhfsistemas.util.StrUtils;

@Entity
@Table(name="CADFUN")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "Funcionario.AllAttributes", includeAllAttributes = true)
})

public class Funcionario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3284546527564750294L;

public static final String TIPO_FUNCIONARIO = "F";
public static final String TIPO_ADMINISTRADOR = "A";

@Id
@Column(name = "fun_cracha")
private Double cracha;

@Column(name = "fun_descricao", length = 70, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(name = "fun_nome_reduzido", length = 20)
private String nomeReduzido;

@Column(name = "fun_email", length = 254, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "fun_cpf_numero", length = 20)
private String cpf;

@Column(name = "fun_rg_numero", length = 12)
private String rg;

@Column(name = "fun_data_nascimento")
private Date dataNascimento;    

@Column(name = "fun_codigo", nullable = false)
private Float registro;

@Column(name = "fun_digito")
private Float digitoRegistro;

@Column(name = "fun_pis_float")
private Long pis;

@Column(name = "fun_pis_numero", length = 20)
private String pisString;

@Column(name = "fun_data_de_admissao", nullable = false)
private Date dataAdmissao;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_empresa", nullable = false)
private Empresa empresa;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_cargo")
private Cargo cargo;

@Column(name = "fun_departamento")
private Float departamento;

@Column(name = "fun_setor")
private Float setor;

@Column(name = "fun_secao")
private Float secao;    

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_contrato_trabalho", nullable = false)
private ContratoTrabalho contratoTrabalho;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_prioridades", nullable = false)
private Prioridade prioridade;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_categoria")
private Categoria categoria;

@Column(name = "c80")
private Double crachaGestor;    

@Column(name = "fun_cracha_alfa")
private String codAux;

@Column(name = "fun_senha_terminal")
private Integer senhaRep;

@Column(name = "fun_salario")
private BigDecimal salario;

@Column(name = "fun_administrador_rep")
private String admRep;

@Column(name = "fun_habilitar_teclado")
private String habilitarTeclado;

@Column(name = "fun_rg_emissao")
private Date dataRg;

@Column(name = "fun_rg_orgao", length = 10)
private String orgaoRg;

@Column(name = "fun_ctps_numero", length = 15)
private String numeroCtps;

@Column(name = "fun_ctps_serie", length = 6)
private String serieCtps;

@Column(name = "fun_ctps_orgao", length = 10)
private String orgaoCtps;

@Column(name = "fun_habilitacao_prof", length = 20)
private String habilitacaoProfissional;

@Column(name = "fun_telefone", length = 30)
private String telefone;

@Column(name = "fun_endereco", length = 40)
private String endereco;

@Column(name = "fun_cidade", length = 20)
private String cidade;

@Column(name = "fun_estado", length = 2)
private String estado;

@Column(name = "fun_cep", length = 9)
private String cep;

@Column(name = "fun_envia_relatorios_email")
private String enviaRelatoriosEmail;

@Column(name = "fun_email_relatorios", length = 100)
private String emailRelatorios;

@Column(name = "fun_tipo_usuario_flexweb", length = 1)
private String tipoUsuarioWeb;

@Column(name = "fun_horas_extras", length = 1)
private String horasExtras;

@Column(name = "fun_tipo_de_funcionario", length = 1)
private String tipoDeFuncionario;

@Column(name = "fun_regime", length = 1)
private String regime;

@Transient
private boolean gestor;
```

EDIT 2: aqui tem um exemplo de uma classe na qual faço referência a FUNCIONARIO(CADFUN) inclusive utilizando a coluna fun_empresa normalmente:

```
package x.y.z.model.tenancy;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDCMP")
public class ComponenteOrdemServico implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1459696828398449480L;
@Id
@Column(name = "orc_sequencia", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "orc_empresa", referencedColumnName = "fun_empresa", nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "orc_funcionario", referencedColumnName = "fun_codigo", nullable = false) })
private Funcionario funcionario;

@Column(name = "orc_ordem_servico")
private String ordemServico;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Funcionario getFuncionario() {
    return funcionario;
}

public void setFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario) {
    this.funcionario = funcionario;
}

public String getOrdemServico() {
    return ordemServico;
}

public void setOrdemServico(String ordemServico) {
    this.ordemServico = ordemServico;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s[codigo=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getId());
}
```

}

EDIT 3: um comentário.. como citado ali em cima, eu estava adicionando classe por classe que deveria ser editado o crachá do funcionário, porém quando chegou em uma certa quantidade ele começou a dar esse erro.. se eu apagar por exemplo a anotação @Entity desse ComponenteOrdemServico que postei, a aplicação volta a funcionar, aí se eu adicionar esta anotação novamente ele volta a dar o erro.. por isso nao faz o menor sentido pelo menos para mim (OBS: mexo com spring boot a menos de dois meses)

Comment: O erro é bem claro: `Unable to find column with logical name fun_empresa in table CADFUN` na tabela CADFUN não possui essa coluna que está mapeada na sua classe.

se puder postar o código das entidades junto com DDL da tabela CADFUN.

Comment: Sim estou ciente que este erro está bem explícito, por isso eu disse que não fez sentido para mim já que a coluna fun_empresa existe... postei as imagens no EDIT 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entao, neste bloco

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
@JoinColumn(name = "orc_empresa", referencedColumnName = "fun_empresa", nullable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "orc_funcionario", referencedColumnName = "fun_codigo", nullable = false) })
private Funcionario funcionario;
```

faz referencia a existencia de duas colunas chaves na entidade Funcionario, okay!
acredito que neste momento o JPA ja fica ciente da existencia da coluna "fun_empresa" e sua referencia.

Porem na entidade de Funcionario voce referencia novamente a coluna

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fun_empresa", nullable = false)
private Empresa empresa;
```

Apontando para outra entidade, entao ao meu ver ficou meio confuso, nao consegui captar oque esta tentando realizar, porem acredito que esse seja o ponto do problema.

Desculpas por nao conseguir somente que comentar, pois ainda tenho poucos pontos entao tive de criar uma resposta, agradeço se puder responder assim podemos se ajudar mais.

Comment: boa! obrigado pela opinião, mas explicando porque eu referencio os dois: na classe que referencia o orc_empresa e o orc_funcionario, é porque no sistema um funcionario possui um crachá único independente da empresa que ele pertence, e possui tambem um registro, que pode ser igual se o funcionario for de empresas diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, simplesmente removi todos os `@JoinColumns` e deixei apenas `@JoinColumn` referenciando apenas o código do funcionário, sem a empresa.

Obrigado Jonathan! Foi de grande utilidade sua resposta .